# Docker project using $_SESSION variable not created

Tags: php, docker, session

I just recently took over a project that we are trying to place in docker, using php:7.4-fpm-buster. Previously used an old version of PHP, so the $_SESSION variables were heavily used in the project. Here is the code I have in my PHP file that is failing:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

...and...

```
unset($_SESSION['ListOfRoutings']);
```

I have also echoed sys_get_temp_dir() and it says it is /tmp, it also says the folder it is writing to is writable. The error I am getting:

> Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in
>   /usr/local/src/arc-bis/basketdesign/scripts/ListOfRoutings.php on
>   line 96

Line 96 is the unset call. I have also taken out the if statement, it does not create the session. Is there a way to get $_SESSION to create a variable with just a tmp directory using docker? I tried to create a tmp directory in docker, but that did not work. 
Thanks in advance...

EDIT: Here is the information from phpinfo:

> Session Support enabled
>    Registered save handlers files user   Registered
>   serializer handlers php_serialize php php_binary 
>      DirectiveLocal
>   ValueMaster Value session.auto_startOffOff session.cache_expire180180 session.cache_limiternocachenocache session.cookie_domain*no
>   value**no value* session.cookie_httponly*no
>   value**no value* session.cookie_lifetime00 session.cookie_path// session.cookie_samesite*no
>   value**no value* session.cookie_secure00 session.gc_divisor10001000 session.gc_maxlifetime72007200 session.gc_probability11 session.lazy_writeOnOn session.namePHPSESSIDPHPSESSID session.referer_check*no
>   value**no value* session.save_handler*no
>   value**no value* session.save_path/tmp/tmp session.serialize_handlerphpphp session.sid_bits_per_character44 session.sid_length3232 session.upload_progress.cleanupOnOn session.upload_progress.enabledOnOn session.upload_progress.freq1%1% session.upload_progress.min_freq11 session.upload_progress.namePHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESSPHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS session.upload_progress.prefixupload_progress_upload_progress_ session.use_cookies11 session.use_only_cookies11 session.use_strict_mode00 session.use_trans_sid00

EDIT: Here are some of the things I tried to add to docker. There is a tmp folder inside the ./ root of the project.

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-buster
...
COPY ./docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini.template
COPY ./docker/php/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf.template
...
RUN mkdir /usr/local/src/arc-bis
COPY ./* /usr/local/src/arc-bis/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/local/src/arc-bis/
...
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/arc-bis
```

On php.ini file inside my docker folder:

```
session.save_path = /usr/local/src/arc-bis
```

Comment: yes I did, I cannot find what I need for my particular case.

Comment: *"Previously used an old version of PHP, so the $_SESSION variables were heavily used in the project."* The version of PHP has no bearing on the use of session variables.

Comment: Are you sure `tmp/` is writable inside the Docker container? How are you testing?

Comment: Jay, I am trying to add a tmp/ folder into my project now, hopefully that is all it was. I am sort of a newb with how the structure of files inside docker gets built based on the os I am using.

Comment: I created a tmp folder on my root and it now has the following permissions: drwxr-xr-x. No change in the program.

Comment: @tcoulson If you "created" a temp folder, you'd need to edit your system file(s) to point it to that folder, setting the right permissions (restart services) and making sure that it doesn't fill up. A full folder will not allow any operation to take place. Note: please use the `@member` to ping someone directly.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I did rebuild my project after adding the folder. I also have session.save_path = /tmp in my php.ini file. What are the correct permissions for a docker folder to write SESSION? that is why I am posting here, I need some guidance. TIA.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I updated again to allow for docker code to be analyzed some too. I am not sure how to get all of these folders to point to the proper path.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should test if session_status() returns PHP_SESSION_DISABLED

When you look to the Changelog from session_start you will find :

> 7.1.0     session_start() now returns FALSE and no longer initializes $_SESSION when it failed to start the session.

So may be you should also check the return value from session_start()

You can also call  php_info() and check the session paragraph may be sessions are disable on your docker image. Maybe you need to give your docker image the correct config

Comment: The value of session_status both before and after my session_start call is 0. I amended the phpinfo, looks like it is enabled.

Comment: do you have any experience with docker with $_SESSION, I have session_start and I have session enabled, and it appears I have a tmp file in the root of my project, but I don't think docker is letting it write to that file for some reason.

Comment: I know this is a problem of my tmp folder not being writable, not sure of the code in docker to make it writable. Looking that up now.